# Transformar el circulo de precision de google maps a coordenadas

Tags: php, google-maps, symfony2, symfony

Trabajo en una aplicacion que usa la API de Geolocalizacion de Google Maps para obtener la ubicacion de dispositivos. En la aplicacion puedes crear una geo valla para que la misma te notifique si el dispositivo ha salido de su zona asignada. El problema es que actualmente la aplicacion te envia la notificación si la ubicacion del dispositivo se encuentra fuera e la zona así el circulo de precisión este tocando la zona, quisiera condicionar que si el circulo de precision esta tocando la geo valla no emita la notificacion. Pero no se como medir si el circulo de precision se encuentra dentro de la geo valla.

[image: example]